# How to fix 'ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_ulong instance instead of LP_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES'

Tags: python, django, windows

I'm trying to open `IPython` shell by running the command `python manage.py`shell for django project but I'm not getting the expected output. Instead, I'm getting some weird stuff.

I tried running twice but the same thing is happening again and again.

And the error I'm receiving

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "c:\users\khyati\django\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\khyati\django\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\users\khyati\django\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "c:\users\khyati\django\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\khyati\django\django\core\management\commands\shell.py", line 99, in handle
    return getattr(self, shell)(options)
  File "c:\users\khyati\django\django\core\management\commands\shell.py", line 36, in ipython
    start_ipython(argv=[])
  File "C:\Users\khyati\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 125, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\khyati\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-113>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\khyati\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\khyati\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 317, in initialize
    self.init_shell()
  File "C:\Users\khyati\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 333, in init_shell
    ipython_dir=self.ipython_dir, user_ns=self.user_ns)
  File "C:\Users\khyati\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\khyati\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\interactiveshell.py", line 431, in __init__
    self.init_prompt_toolkit_cli()
  File "C:\Users\khyati\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\interactiveshell.py", line 281, in init_prompt_toolkit_cli
    self._eventloop = create_eventloop(self.inputhook)
  File "C:\Users\khyati\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts.py", line 95, in create_eventloop
    return Loop(inputhook=inputhook, recognize_paste=recognize_win32_paste)
  File "C:\Users\khyati\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\eventloop\win32.py", line 39, in __init__
    self._event = _create_event()
  File "C:\Users\khyati\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\eventloop\win32.py", line 187, in _create_event
    return windll.kernel32.CreateEventA(pointer(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES()), BOOL(True), BOOL(False), None)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_ulong instance instead of LP_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@python.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    c.Application.verbose_crash=True

Python 3.x.x(v3.x.x: ........)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython x.x.x -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

Any help would be appreciated. BTW. I'm using Windows

Comment: There is a collision over the ctypes global `windll.kernel32.CreateEventA.argtypes`, leading to the error "expected `LP_c_ulong` instance instead of `LP_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`".  All parties involved need to stop using `cdll` and `windll`, which cache `CDLL` and `WinDLL` instances, which in turn cache function pointers. Packages should use private `CDLL` and `WinDLL` instances. At best these global `cdll` and `windll` loaders are a convenience for scripts, and even then they're pretty bad since they don't enable `use_errno` or `use_last_error`. They should be deprecated and removed.

Comment: I have a similar problem. On my side it is related to imports. I'm still investigating, but  I saw that the problem ceased to happen by cleaning some of the imports that I did. You could have a look in your code when you import modules

Comment: @ErykSun Based on your comment, I was able to fix this issue for myself. I couldn't start the django ipython shell because it kept crashing with the error in `.../site-packages/prompt_toolkit/eventloop/win32.py`. To try it out, I patched `win32.py` by replacing `from ctypes import windll` with `from ctypes import LibraryLoader, WinDLL` and `windll = LibraryLoader(WinDLL)` and it worked like a charm.